# Reset button for each preview image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't want to create a remove button; for each images which are previewed before they are going to be uploaded. The reason is because each image has a unique id, so that if it uses a remove button it will mess up the id arrangement when one of the images is removed.

I know this is a little complicated.

How to create a reset button for each images? So, when the user click the reset button, it will open the window of the user computer to pick the new image, and the id of the new picked image is still the same as before.

Here is my code:

```
var ftype = new Array(), count1 = 0;

    $("#imgInput").change(function () {
        readURL(this);

    });
    function readURL(input) {
        var files = input.files;
        var output = document.getElementById("result");



        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var picReader = new FileReader();
            var divid = 'div_' + i;
            var spanid = 'span_' + i;
            var count = 0;
            picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                var picFile = event.target;
                var picnames = files[count].name;
                var mimetypes = picFile.result.split(',');
                var mimetype1 = mimetypes[0];
                var mimetype = mimetype1.split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
                count++;
                count1++;
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + count);
                div.setAttribute('class', 'divclass');
                if (mimetype.match('image')) {
                    div.innerHTML = "<img id='img_" +  count1 + "' class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + picnames + "' width='96' height='80' alt='Item Image' style='position:relative;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;' data-valu='" + mimetype + "'/>";

                }

                output.insertBefore(div, null);

            });

            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
```

[MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/3g5qv72a/)

Comment: You should probably post also your HTML and set-up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), as right now it is hard to tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I am trying to do is still not done at all in my code. But what I want to get is to create a reset botton for each images. I hope anyone can help me to do that.

Comment: Try making the listener a named function instead of anonymous. This will let you reuse it for any button. Try that first.

Comment: @Quentin Can you help me to do that because I still have no idea on that.

Comment: Study this page in depth https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener Once you have tried some things come back, and update your code if it's not working.

Comment: By the way. You're quite close to getting what you want. Take your time, and think about it. I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: Could you just help me and show me on the answer table how to do that so that I can figure it out, please? I have taken my time and thought  about it for more than two hours but still not got the idea because all the code I've got was from the helps of SO's users.